# React - Can't read state of username / password

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login form and I'm sending the username and password through the body of the request to my express app.

When putting the username and password into the body of the request I am receiving an error saying: `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`.

Can anyone tell me why on this line the browser cannot read the state?

Heres the code:

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state ={
        username: "",
        password: "",
        errorMessage: ""
      };
    }
    handleEmailChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        username: event.target.value
      })
    }
    handlePasswordChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        password: event.target.value
      })
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/user', {
        credentials : 'include',
        method      : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify({
          username : this.state.username,
          password : this.state.password
        })
      })
      .then(res  => res.json())
      .then(json => {

        // If the registration was successful
        if (json.success) {
          navigate('/account');
        }  
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: 'An unknown error occurred',
        });
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className = "login-form">
          <Form onSubmit = {this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="formGroupEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}/>
            </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" onChange = {this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)}/>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button text = "Log In"/>
      </Form>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue here is related to context of handleSubmit, using bind or implementing it as an arrow function would solve your problem. Please do check the duplicate for more info. If however it still doesn't solve your problem, I would be happy to remove the duplicate

Comment: Oh I missed that. Thanks!